# Angular resource - bind to Rails RESTful API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, angularjs

I was looking at AngularJs Resource documentation and it states that default actions
for accessing API are:
**{'get':    {method:'GET'},
  'save':   {method:'POST'},
  'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true},
  'remove': {method:'DELETE'},
  'delete': {method:'DELETE'} };**

This is a bit different from Rails RESTful API where we have **index,show,new,create,edit,update and discard**. Is there an "automatic" way
to bind these two without writing the path manually? Thanks!

ps. why remove and delete, where's put for update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ngResource simply uses different names for usual REST conventions. So for example:

```
var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
var user = User.get({userId:123}, function() {
  // do something with user
});
```

In this example `User.get()`sends the following request `GET /user/123` which Rails routing logic passes to UserController#show action.

Regarding the update method, you can simply create one yourself:

```
var User = $resource('/user/:id', {}, {
    update: {
      method: 'PUT'
    }

}
```

Comment: See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource and particularly the information about 'action'.

Comment: Here's another example http://blog.berylliumwork.com/2012/09/tutorials-on-angularjs-and-rails-5.html